# To Open an activity on the click of Expandable list view child

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I want to open a new activity on the click of child of an expandable listview. I tried following code **but it is neither working nor giving any errors.**

```
 Exp_list.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent mum;
            if(groupPosition==0){
                mum = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Example.class);
                startActivity(mum);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Following is the code for adapter class

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context _context;
private List<String> Travels_Header;
private HashMap<String, List<String>> Details_Child; 

public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> Travels_Header, HashMap<String, List<String>> Details_Child) {
    this._context = context;
    this.Travels_Header = Travels_Header;
    this.Details_Child = Details_Child;
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int parent, int child) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.Details_Child.get(this.Travels_Header.get(parent)).get(child);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int parent, int child) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return child;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int parent, int child, boolean lastChild, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parentView) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    final String childText = (String) getChild(parent, child);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_child, null);
    }

    TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.Details_Child.get(this.Travels_Header.get(parent)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.Travels_Header.get(parent);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return this.Travels_Header.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return parent;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int parent, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parentView) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(parent);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int parent, int child) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return true;
}
}
```

Tried various methods to execute this code.

Comment: put logs in onChildClick and print  groupPosition value in it. add those logs here also

Comment: put clicklistenr on convertview and start activtiy from there try.

Comment: @SurenderKumar can u please post the code for the same..

Answer (score 0):

Try this code i had make changes in your code only.

```
@Override
        public View getChildView(int parent, int child, boolean lastChild, View convertView,
                ViewGroup parentView) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            final String childText = (String) getChild(parent, child);

            if (convertView == null) {
                LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view_child, null);
            }

            TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            txtListChild.setText(childText);

    //convertview listener
        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
    //parent position
        if(parent==0){
    //child positon
        if(child==0){
        Intent i = new Intent(context, activity.class);
        in.addFlags(Intent.FLAF_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(i);
        }
        }
        }
                });
            return convertView;

    }
```

Comment: Ur code didnt helped.. It is not opening another activity

Comment: when you want to open new activity on group click or child click.?

Comment: i want to open an activity on child click

Comment: ok...first check when you pressed child click is the position is correct or not by using LOG in code in convertview click like Log.e("parent pos" ,""+parent);, same as for child position.

Answer (score 0):

```
Exp_list.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
    public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
            int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            switch (groupPosition) {          // the First you must know the group position
                case 0:                       // Here your Group position the first Group
                switch (childPosition) {
                    case 7:                   // Here your Child position
                        startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Example.class));
                        break;                // this break for Child
                }
                    break;                    // this break for Group
                case 1:                       // again here your Group  position the Second Group
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 9:               // again here your Child position
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Example.class));
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 9:
                            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Example.class));
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. Adding a little commentary to your answer would improve it. Would you please [edit] it and add some explanation? Thank you!